# Fatal Error- include_once(Faker/Provider/en_US/Barcode.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, faker

While trying to user faker using composer,

```
"require-dev": {
"codeception/codeception": "^2.2",
"fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4"
}
```

we are getting the below error.

> include_once(Faker/Provider/en_US/Barcode.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory

**Framework - Zend**

Code used below.

```
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();
echo $faker->name;
```

Included the vendor/autoload.php in the entry point of application also.

There is no file in the provider/en_US folder also.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: it's weird that you use include with composer. an `autoload.php` file should be included once with a `use` class definition. more info can be found here - https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Ya. if we are using the composer, then we don't need to include the autoload file. But how can we solve the above fatal error?

Comment: so I can see the file located here - Faker/Provider/Barcode.php without en_US. - https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/master/src/Faker/Provider/Barcode.php

Comment: Yes. But when we don't pass the locale, it is trying to consider en_US as default locale and trying to find the Barcode under en_US. How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the real issue was the issue with the zend autoloader I was using.

So added the below code to suppress the error.

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);
```